# DocumentDB SQL Query works in Query Explorer but not in C# code

Tags: c#, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I want to get value of a variable(InputAssetId) stored in a document as a string.Wrote the query.It works fine in the QueryExplorer.

```
 this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
 IQueryable<asset> id = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<asset>(
               UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName,CollectionName),
               "SELECT c.InputAssetId FROM c WHERE c.BlobNameDb='BigBuckBunny.mp4' ");
 Console.WriteLine( id.string());
```

Instead of a value stored in the variable,what i got in the console is given below

```
{"query":"SELECT c.InputAssetId FROM c WHERE c.BlobNameDb='BigBuckBunny.mp4' "}
```

Can anyone please give me a solution?

Comment: What's the problem? That looks like a valid SQL query to me.

Comment: What is `asset`? And by the way, shouldn't you get a `IQueryable<string>` if you select the id only?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I want to print the value of "InputAssetId" in the console.Instead what i got in the console is given in the question.This is the problem.

Comment: @C.Champagne Tried using IQueryable<string>. Still getting the same output.

Comment: Sorry - been up too long.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you aren't actually ever executing the query you've created. The correct code would be something along those lines:

```
this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
var query = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<asset>(
         ... your LiNQ or SQL query...
    .AsDocumentQuery();

var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<string>();
Console.WriteLine(result.ToList().FirstOrDefault());
```

You may want to use TOP 1 in the query (and not FeedOptions.MaxItemCount = 1, as the latter is badly named - it actually means how many items per feed request are returned at the most. Using low MaxItemCount can lead to great number of useless queries).

Answer (score 0):

Well I still don't know all the  API that well but I would use [Linq](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#linq-to-documentdb-sql) with C#. `.

You should write it more or less that way :

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };

IQueryable<Asset> assetQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Asset>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName),
```

queryOptions)
        .Where(o => o.BlobNameDb == "BigBuckBunny.mp4");

```
string id = assetQuery.First().InputAssetId ;
```

From what I can read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt414460(v=azure.100).aspx?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery%60%601%22)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) you want to use SQL query, you have to pass it as a [`SqlQuerySpec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.sqlqueryspec.aspx) so your code could become (haven't tested the solution though):

```
IQueryable<string> assetQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Asset>(
          UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName), 
          new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT c.InputAssetId FROM c WHERE c.BlobNameDb='BigBuckBunny.mp4'"),
          queryOptions)
string id = assetQuery.First();
```